# realloc function error: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated

Tags: c

I was trying to use realloc function in implementing a string combination function. This function is going to merge two strings, leftPiece and rightPiece, the tail of left piece and head of right piece has overlapped characters with number num_overlap. Because the input strings are perfectly sized, I have to reallocate the string so that I have enough space to concatenate the two strings. My function is as follows:

```
char* merge_overlap (char** leftPiece, char** rightPiece, int num_overlap) {
      printf("in merge_overlap, left is %s, right is %s \n", *leftPiece, *rightPiece);

    *leftPiece = (char*) realloc(*leftPiece, (strlen(*leftPiece) + strlen(*rightPiece) - abs(num_overlap) + 1) * sizeof(char) );
    *leftPiece = strcat(*leftPiece, *rightPiece + abs(num_overlap));
    return *leftPiece;
}
```

in this function I firstly reallocate the space for left piece then concatenate the two strings. but when I compile I got errors:

malloc: *** error for object 0x100000f25: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

can any one see what this problem is?

new added contents: 
Actually the the original string array is rearranged prior to passing into this function. The string array contains many strings, I firstly tried to find out two strings that has overlapped substring. Then I rearranged the index of the two strings so that the left piece always has a lower index. the code is as follows:                                                                            char *temp = frags[j];
                        frags[j] = frags[i];
                        frags[i] = temp;    That might make the error happens.

problem solved :
the code is adapted as follows:

```
char *result = malloc(strlen(*leftPiece) + strlen(*rightPiece) -abs(num_overlap) + 1);
        strcpy(result, *leftPiece);
        strcat(result, *rightPiece + abs(num_overlap));
        return result;
```

Comment: The error may be much earlier when you allocate memory for `leftPiece`.

Comment: What did you pass to `merge_overlap()`?

Comment: How do you call `merge_overlap` and do you `malloc` memory for `leftPiece` before calling it?

Comment: @EOF I passed a char * to merger_overlap. it's just a char pointer which has some string in it.

Comment: @LeonloveKaren: Where did you *get that `char *` from*?

Comment: @pzaenger no malloc is used for leftPiece before I call it.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code shown. It is in the code that allocates the space that is ultimately passed to this function via `*leftPiece`. You'll have to track that down. Consider whether you can use [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/). If it is supposed to be allocated anew, then ensure that `*leftPiece` is a null pointer before the function is called. The error message is pretty explicit: it says the space being reallocated was not allocated, and you've just confirmed that it wasn't. What more do you expect? C is not a language that holds your hand and makes sure you make no mistakes.

Comment: Is `leftPiece` previously allocated with `malloc`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Calling `strlen()` on a NULL-pointer?

Comment: @EOF: then at least you'd (probably) get a straight-forward crash.  The code needs to be reviewed carefully to decide what its behaviour should be.  But you're right, if `*leftPiece` could be a null pointer, then the code has to be adjusted more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that `merge_overlap()` requires you to pass in a `leftPiece` that was originally `malloc()`ed, but you passed in a different kind of `char *`.

> **You can only `realloc` a string that was originally allocated with `malloc`.**

To fix the problem you need to `malloc()` the original `leftPiece`.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

As J. Leffler and others point out, your error is in your prior code, most likely that `leftPiece` was not previously declared as a compatible pointer, and given the working of your function, not one previously allocated with `malloc` (or similar). In order to `realloc`, the pointer must not have been statically declared. Otherwise, your function works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* merge_overlap (char** leftPiece, char** rightPiece, int num_overlap) 
{
    *leftPiece = realloc (*leftPiece, 
                        (strlen (*leftPiece) + 
                        strlen (*rightPiece) - 
                        abs(num_overlap) + 1));
    *leftPiece = strcat (*leftPiece, *rightPiece + abs(num_overlap));

    return *leftPiece;
}

int main (void) {

    char *str1 = strdup ("A quick brown fox jumps");
    char *str2 = strdup ("jumps over the lazy dog.");

    printf ("\n str1 : %s\n"
            " str2 : %s\n", str1, str2);

    merge_overlap (&str1, &str2, 5);

    printf ("\n merged:\n\n"
            " str1 : %s\n\n", str1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/mergoverlap

 str1 : A quick brown fox jumps
 str2 : jumps over the lazy dog.

 merged:

 str1 : A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: thanks a lot. (plz look at my original post, which I added the following comment)  Actually the the original string array is rearranged prior to passing into this function. The string array contains many strings, I firstly tried to find out two strings that has overlapped substring. Then I rearranged the index of the two strings so that the left piece always has a lower index. the code is as follows:         char *temp = frags[j];  frags[j] = frags[i];
frags[i] = temp;    That might make the error happens.

Comment: The key is `leftPiece` must have originally been declared as `char *leftPiece;` and then allocated and filled with something interesting, before you call `merge_overlap`. In the example above `strdup()` both allocates with `malloc` and copies to `str1` and `str2`.